# Postgres Hibernate Primary Key generation Issue

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to insert a record in Employee table with Hibernate ORM but keep getting an error as :

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in 
com.example.helloworld.entities.Employee entry (don't flush the Session 
after an exception occurs)
```

If I pass ID value then it works fine but although I have used `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` it does not generate `'id'` automatically. Any help is appreciated! Details on DB schema and entity code is as given below.

DB Engine: Postgres

ORM : Hibernate

I have following two tables :

Table Name  **Employee**:

---

```
Column Name |  Type      |  Length    |  Not Null  | Default
name        | Varchar    |  64        |  true      | NULL 
id          |  int8      |  19        |  true      |nextval(Employee_id::regclass)
company_id  |  int8     |19           |  true      | NULL
```

Table  #Company

```
Column Name |  Type      |  Length    |  Not Null  | Default
Cname       | Varchar    |  64        |  true      | NULL 
id          |  int8      |  19        |  true      | nextval(Company_id::regclass)
```

```
 area       |  varchar    |64          |  true      | NULL
```

Entity Java Classes for above tables :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {

    public Employee() {super();}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    private long company_id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;

   /**
   setters and getters
   **/
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Company")
public class Company {

    public Company() {super();}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "area")
    private String area;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "cname")
    private String cname;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    private Set<Employee> employees;

   /**
   setters and getters
   **/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator="seq_name_generated_in_db")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_name_generated_in_db", sequenceName="seq_name_generated_in_db", initialValue = 1 , allocationSize=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Postgres.
Try adding a `SequenceGenerator` to your `id` field:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_EMPLOYEE")
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_EMPLOYEE", sequenceName="SEQ_EMPLOYEE", allocationSize=1)
@NotNull
private long id;
```

Replace `SEQ_EMPLOYEE` with the name of the sequence in the database.

Comment: No difference in error. Got same error such as :
<pre>
ERROR [2017-10-31 14:47:14,721] org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.example.helloworld.entities.Employee entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
</pre>

Comment: I forgot to change also the GeneratedValue. I have edited my post.

Comment: Thanks, @Wesley that worked! It started generating ID from 10 which I do not understand why also I have few questions on it as follows: 


1)   Is SEQ type generation not going to create any problem with respect uniqueness? 


2)  Any limitation on a number of ids can be generated?


3)  Why 'Identity Generation' did not work in my case? It works in a single table with no foreign reference.